# Rails extend Module in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, controller

I am trying to write a module and I want to replace that module with my action in my controller. For that I have created a module called test inside my controller folder which is. Where I want to put my action my controller action code is:

```
 def test
  rain_fall_type = "test"
  year  = ""
  compare = params[:compare]
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render json: rain_fall_type }
  end
end
```

I want to put this code inside my module code I have added this code into my module whose code is:

```
 module Test 
    def test
        rain_fall_type = "params[:rain_fall_type]
        views  = params[:views]"
        year  = ""
        compare = params[:compare]
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render json: rain_fall_type }
        end
    end 
end
```

And I am trying to extend this into my controller so I am putting extend Test into my controller but I am getting this error:

```
The action 'test' could not be found for ProductionProductivity7sController
```

When I remove def test from my module and put this code in controller like this:

```
 def test
   extend Test
 end
```

And I remove def test from module and changed it to:

```
   module Test 
        rain_fall_type = "params[:rain_fall_type]
        views  = params[:views]"
        year  = ""
        compare = params[:compare]
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render json: rain_fall_type }
        end

end
```

When I am doing this I am getting this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `params' for Test:Module
```

What should I do to just replace my test action into my module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good task for [`concerns`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html), here is an example:

your controller code:

```
class ProductionProductivity7sController < ApplicationController
  include Concerns::MyAwesomeModule
end
```

your module placed in `app/controllers/concerns/my_awesome_module.rb`:

```
module Concerns
  module MyAwesomeModule
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      # here you can use controller level methods
      # like `before_action` 
    end

    def the_action_name
      # your logic goes here
      # you can use all variables from original controller
      # for e.g. `params`, `render` and so on.
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I am getting this erro cannot load such file -- /home/nilay/rail/rails-backend/app/controllers/my_awesome_module.rb

Comment: It's works for me, you're  doing something wrong, double check your code.

Comment: I added my_awesome_module.rb into my controller/concern folder what else do I need

Comment: There can be a lot of issues, from typo in your code to wrong filenames, I can't help you in this case, I use the code above and it's works like a charm.

Comment: your answer is wrong edit your answer  I modified your code have a look and it is working. https://gist.github.com/nwoow/1302dd43b5263d30dda42fc77755a5f0

Comment: It's not wrong, as I say it's **an example**, which show you a way how to it. Anyway it's good what you're find a bug. Happy coding!